# What is the meaning of asctime?

Tags: history, c

I see asctime in C, C++ and Python. What does the abbreviation mean? All those functions of max 8 characters are pretty obvious (strcpy e.g.) but this one eludes me.

Is it ASCII time? Is it 'as ctime' or it is 'as character time'?

Google: no help.

Comment: you can type `man asctime` on your unix machine, or just google `asctime` or `man asctime`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: Interestingly, the POSIX man page (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asctime.3p.html) makes no mention of ASCII, but the Linux man page (glibc: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html) describes it as: **transform date and time to broken-down
       time or ASCII**  (The same page covers multiple functions, including ones that fill a struct, hence the "broken down").

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [ANSI C design rationale document](https://home.nvg.org/%7Eskars/programming/C_Rationale.pdf) implies that the name stands for ‘ASCII time’:

> #### 4.12.3.1 The `asctime` function
>
> Although the name of this function suggests a conflict with the principle of removing ASCII dependencies from the Standard, the name has been retained due to prior art.

The function was added in [Unix V7](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/3/ctime) where it is described as

> Asctime converts a broken-down time to ASCII and returns a pointer to a 26-character string.

Comment: asctime is a badly designed function anyhow. I'd recommend using strftime instead. Similar to how strtol is better to work with than atoi